# Changing state of a specific child component without refs

Tags: reactjs

I am implementing some sort of a typing test app with React. I have got the following hierarchy of components:

ContainerForWords 1->N Word 1->N Letter.

At first I tried doing it with refs, so I can change words' state depending on the user input, but it became a nightmare since refs are not designed to be used like this (they do not trigger re-renders). Is there any other valid way of accessing child components and changing their state from parent?

```
// ========== GeneratedTextAreaContainer
export const GeneratedTextAreaContainer = (): JSX.Element => {
  const { isRestartScheduled, setRestartScheduledStatus } = useContext(RestartContext);
  const trainingConfiguration = useAppSelector((store) => store.data.training);
  const wordRefs = useRef<WordRef[]>([]);

  const queryResult = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['generatedText'],
    queryFn: async () => {
      const data = await trainingHttpClient.getGeneratedText({
        ...trainingConfiguration,
        languageId: trainingConfiguration.languageInfo.id
      });

      wordRefs.current = [];
      setRestartScheduledStatus(false);

      return data;
    },
    enabled: isRestartScheduled
  });

  const generatedText = queryResult.data?.value ?? [];

  const wordElements = generatedText.map((wordLetters, wordIndex) => (
    <Word
      key={`word_${wordIndex}`}
      letters={wordLetters}
      isActive={wordIndex === 0}
      ref={(ref: WordRef) => {
        wordRefs.current.push(ref);
      }}
    />
  ));

  return (
    <>
      {isRestartScheduled ? (
        <LoaderElement />
      ) : (
        <GeneratedTextAreaFragment words={wordElements} wordRefs={wordRefs.current} />
      )}
    </>
  );
};

// ========== GeneratedTextAreaFragment

interface Props {
  words: ReactNode;
  wordRefs: WordRef[];
}

interface PositionInfo {
  positionInWord: number;
  wordIndex: number;
}

export const GeneratedTextAreaFragment = (props: Props): JSX.Element => {
  const [rerenderTrigger, setRerenderTrigger] = useState(false);
  const [positionInfo, setPositionInfo] = useState<PositionInfo>({
    positionInWord: 0,
    wordIndex: 0
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setRerenderTrigger(!rerenderTrigger);
  }, []);

  const activeWord = props.wordRefs.find((w) => w.isActive);
  console.log(props.wordRefs);

  const keyDownHandler = (event: KeyboardEvent<HTMLDivElement>): void => {
    const char = event.key;
    const currentLetter = activeWord?.letterRefs[positionInfo.positionInWord];
    if (currentLetter?.character === char) {
      currentLetter?.setStatus('correct');
    } else {
      currentLetter?.setStatus('incorrect');
    }

    if (
      activeWord?.letterRefs !== undefined &&
      positionInfo.positionInWord === activeWord?.letterRefs?.length - 1
    ) {
      const newActiveWord = props.wordRefs[positionInfo.wordIndex + 1];
      activeWord.setIsActive(false);
      newActiveWord.setIsActive(true);
    }

    setPositionInfo((oldPositionInfo) => {
      if (
        activeWord !== undefined &&
        oldPositionInfo.positionInWord === activeWord?.letterRefs.length
      ) {
        return { wordIndex: oldPositionInfo.wordIndex + 1, positionInWord: 0 };
      }

      return {
        wordIndex: oldPositionInfo.wordIndex,
        positionInWord: oldPositionInfo.positionInWord + 1
      };
    });
  };

  return (
    <FocusLock>
      <Box sx={styles.wordsContainer} tabIndex={0} onKeyDown={keyDownHandler}>
        {props.words}
      </Box>
    </FocusLock>
  );
};

// ========== Word

interface Props {
  isActive: boolean;
  letters: string[];
}

interface WordRef {
  isActive: boolean;
  setIsActive: (isActive: boolean) => void;
  letterRefs: LetterRef[];
}

const Word = forwardRef((props: Props, ref) => {
  const [rerenderTrigger, setRerenderTrigger] = useState(false);
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(props.isActive);
  const letterRefs = useRef<LetterRef[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setRerenderTrigger(!rerenderTrigger);
  }, []);

  useImperativeHandle(
    ref,
    () => {
      return {
        isActive,
        setIsActive,
        letterRefs: letterRefs.current
      };
    },
    [isActive, letterRefs]
  );

  const letterElements = props.letters.map((character, characterIndex) => {
    return (
      <Letter
        key={`char_${characterIndex}`}
        character={character}
        ref={(ref: LetterRef) => letterRefs.current.push(ref)}
      />
    );
  });

  console.log(letterRefs.current);

  return <Box sx={styles.word}>{letterElements}</Box>;
});

Word.displayName = 'Word';

export { Word };
export type { WordRef };

// ========== Letter

type Status = 'initial' | 'correct' | 'incorrect';

interface Props {
  character: string;
}

interface LetterRef {
  character: string;
  setStatus: (status: Status) => void;
}

const Letter = forwardRef((props: Props, ref) => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState<Status>('initial');

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
    return {
      character: props.character,
      setStatus
    };
  });

  const getStylesBasedOnState = (): SxProps => {
    if (status === 'correct') {
      return styles.correct;
    }
    if (status === 'incorrect') {
      return styles.incorrect;
    }
    return styles.initial;
  };

  return <Typography sx={{ ...getStylesBasedOnState() }}>{props.character}</Typography>;
});

Letter.displayName = 'Letter';

export { Letter };
export type { Status, LetterRef };
```

Comment: simply props? or context? you should try to include a MINIMAL example to have better/more specific answers.

Comment: If the parent decides/manages the value, then this should be a prop not a state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Lift the state up

[Old official documentation](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

[Brand new official documentation](https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components)

Hard to answer precisely without an example, but if you want to change the child's state in the parent, it likely means that the parent needs to hold its children states. Something like

```
function ContainerForWords(){
  const [wordsStates, setWordsStates] = useState( /* initial states as an array */);

  const changeWordState(wordIndex, newState){
   setWordsStates(previousStates => {
    const newStates = [...previousStates]; // copy previous state as we shouldn't mutate it directly
    newStates[wordIndex] = newState;
    return newStates;
   })
  }   
    
  return wordsStates.maps(wordState => <Word state={wordState} />);
}
```

Alternatively if the order doesn't matter, instead of an array you can use a Map/Object word -> state. Note to not modify the map/object directly, you always need to copy it first as states are meant to be immutable.

Comment: Added related code

Comment: @tokechu could you please trim down your code to remove all the parts unrelated to your question and display a [MINIMAL example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

At a first glance, the generic solution I suggested would work and the parent need to keep the index of which word is active, instead of each child keeping an `active` flag. Your example looks a lot like the one in the new official documentation I shared

Answer (score -2):

Redux or another State Management Tool is recommended.

https://redux.js.org/

Comment: Instead of simply providing the answer directly, try writing a detailed comment that explains the solution, as long as the explanation is not too lengthy.